# How to get the count of messages in System.Threading.Channels.Channel

Tags: asp.net-core

A simple question:

Is there any way to get the number of messages in a System.Threading.Channels.Channel instance? Seems a bit odd there doesn't seem to be any builtin way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a `channel.Reader.Count`.
Note: this is counting the existing messages in the channel, not the channel capacity.

Reference:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-2.reader?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Channels_Channel_2_Reader
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1?view=net-5.0

Comment: Interesting. Do I have to update my version of .Net Core or something like that? Because in my .Net Standard 2.0 project I don't have that property.

https://ibb.co/SBrgbrf

Comment: I was referring to the official documentation. You can click the link and see the `Applies to` section for different version requirements. For .Net Core looks like it is at least in 3.0, 3.1 @BineG

Comment: I see that the Count property just throws NotSupportedException